# Django 1.9 broken redirect after custom 404 page

Tags: django, redirect

On Django 1.9 multilingual site **domain.com/** used to redirect to **domain.com/en/** automatically.

Now, when I put a custom 404.html in top level templates dir, Django no longer redirects to the language:

- **domain.com/** throws server error 500 instead of redirecting to **domain.com/en/**
  How keep custom 404 error page and get no server error 500?

### Code:

urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^robots\.txt$', lambda r: HttpResponse(" ", content_type="text/plain"))
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^rosetta/', include('rosetta.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('mp.urls', namespace='mp', app_name='mp')),
)
```

Dirs:

```
- project_folder
- app
-- templates
--- app_name
---- all templates
--- 404.html (had to put higher than app subdir, for Django to see it)
- project
-- settings, etc
```

view:

```
class Main(View):
    def get(self, request):
        c = get_seo_stuff("home")
        t = "app/home.html"
        return render(request, t, c)

    def post(self, request):
        pass
```

Code is pretty simple and it used to work just before the 404.html commit.

Comment: can you include some of the code?

Comment: sure, which piece of code?

Comment: your view and maybe your template folder structure

Comment: added some code

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It was a multisite Django installation, and when I added a custom 404.html in one app, Django tried showing it on other apps as well.
The 404.html contained urls and stuff, not resolvable from the other tenant apps, resulting in Server Error 500.

Solution: add custom 404 handlers or use neutral 404.html page.